# Reverting to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, 16.10

My computer currently dual boots Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.10. After I partioned my hard drive and installed Ubuntu 16.10, I found out that I had gotten the 32 bit version. I want to be able to revert back to Ubuntu 16.04 (which I already have a bootable for), and delete Ubuntu 16.10 off of my hard drive. What are the steps that I need to follow to accomplish this? I am a little bit of a novice when it comes to this kind of thing, so a step-by-step guide would be greatly appreciated!!!

EDIT: When I say "revert", I mean how do I go about reinstalling. How do I delete the Ubuntu 16.10 partition, and install 16.04/17.10 in its place? Also I am dual booting with grub, and from what I have researched, deleting Ubuntu could mess with my ability to access my windows partition. Sorry for the lack of Clarity.

Comment: You can't "revert" to an older version really. You should back up your data and then re-install the version you want (whether that's 16.04 or 17.10, as 16.10 is no longer supported, and 17.04 will only be supported until January).

Comment: When I say "revert", I mean how do I go about reinstalling. How do I delete the Ubuntu 16.10 partition, and install 16.04/17.10 in its place? Also I am dual booting with grub, and from what I have researched, deleting Ubuntu could mess with my ability to access my windows partition. Sorry for the lack of Clarity.

Comment: You just do a fresh install over the top

Comment: Right. You don't "delete" it exactly. You do a fresh install over top.

Comment: So during the Ubuntu16.04 installation, will it give me an option to install over the previous partition?